# Designing a Carry lookahead unit using EEPROMs, creates oscillator

Tags: eeprom, adder, alu, carry-look-ahead, homebrew-cpu

I have read something about `CLUs` (Carry Lookahead Units) and want to build one. I have settled on a design using `EEPROMS` as adders and `CLU`. In the picture below, you can see a schematic CLU implementation. In my version, I think the best would be to swap the schematic blocks with `EEPROMs`. (One `EEPROM` per adder and one for the `CLU`, there are plenty of chips available for this format.) But the more I looked at it it seems that we will create some sort of an oscillator.

Let me explain.

Let's assume that one EEPROM has a `200us` (just for example) delay before the data on the output becomes valid. Meanwhile, the output can be "whatever" it wants. But in that time, the outputs of the CLU EEPROM are sending back to individual adders their Carry-in signal. so if that signal changes, the output changes, and again, we have a `200us` delay before the data becomes valid. So that means the individual adder can change its outputs (Propagate and Generate) And that completes the circle back to the CLU and it loops again. So we have basically an oscillator.

Am I right? I yes, how can we make it otherwise than to latch it and wait for the next clock cycle?

Thanks

[image: CLU]
[CLU picture URL](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Lookahead_carry_unit)

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not going to oscillate if you design it correctly. For example, C4 depends only A[0:3], B[0:3], and the carry input. If those inputs are stable then the value of C4 should become stable and not change, regardless of what happens to the other inputs to the CLU. Sometime later C8 will become stable, then C12 will become stable, and finally C16 will become stable.

Comment: What you are talking about is a ripple carry adder with Propagate and Generate instead of Carry, basically. But for technical reasons, i (if it is possible) i want to have just one eeprom as CLU, so the theory what pin becomes stable is not possible, if just one input isn't  stable - then the whole thing would not be stable